# I need a form to appear when I click on a button

Tags: javascript, html, button

This is a button I created in the body of the HTML file:

`<button type="button" value ="Add Child" onclick="addChild();">`

When I click on this button, I need it to append the body and add a form. some of the solutions I found stated that I have to have a form element created in the body to start with. However I do not want the form to appear until I click on this button and I can't seem to know what to write in the javascript function for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<button onclick="showForm()">Show the form</button>
<form id="formElement" style="display: none;">
 ...
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showForm() {
        document.getElementById('formElement').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There's of course room for improvements to this plain JS snippet (use jQuery instead of plain JavaScript, do not use inline JavaScript, use CSS instead of inline styles and of course, do not use onclick, but set a click listener to the element)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't want the form to appear but it's existence in the HTML would not be a problem.

So, design your form on your page, then, in your CSS, add `display: none;` to the form.

Then with Javascript you can change the display.

In this example, we give the form the ID 'form1'...

HTML:

```
<button type="button" value ="Add Child" onclick="addChild();">
<form id="form1">...</form>
```

CSS:

```
#form1 {
  display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function addChild() {
  document.getElementById('form1').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: I am still a beginner it is only my second project, I did not know that I can use such a method, it's very helpful thank you